# A wrong column is selected when addressing individual elements of unlimited polymorphic dummy argument

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Consider the following Fortran program:

```
program test_prg
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  integer, allocatable :: arr(:, :)

  arr = reshape([(i, i = 1, 100)], [10, 10])
  do i = 1, 3
    print *, 'Column', i
    call write_array(arr(1:2, i)) 
  end do

contains

  subroutine write_array(array)
    class(*), intent(in) :: array(:)
    integer :: i

    do i = 1, size(array)
      select type (elem => array(i))
        type is (integer)
          print '(I0)', elem
      end select
    end do
  end subroutine


  subroutine write_array_alt(array)
    class(*), intent(in) :: array(:)
    integer :: i

    select type (array)
      type is (integer)
        print '(I0)', array
    end select
  end subroutine

end program
```

Compiled with gfortran 9.3.0, the program prints:

```
 Column           1
1
2
 Column           2
21
22
 Column           3
41
42
```

As you can see, it skips every other column. If I replace the call to `write_array` with the call to `write_array_alt`, where I `select type` of the whole array and not individual elements, then every column is printed, as expected. Is this a gfortran bug or is this code illegal?

Comment: Not sure about the details but as with other languages like C++, C# and python, integer is a basic type, not a class.  If you treat a basic type as a class, the address calculations will be incorrect.  In the _alt function, the array is treated as a class.

Comment: @cup, an unlimited polymorphic entity is just as type compatible with an intrinsic type entity as it is a with a non-intrinsic type entity.

Comment: Here is a post on comp.lang.fortran asking for opinions https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/HbOdSPPzEHI